# Methods .play() and .pause() doesn't seem to work, when video tag has autoplay attribute

Tags: jquery, video, methods, attributes, tags

I have a video, that has `autoplay loop` attributes. It starts playing as soon as page is loaded.

```
<video id="myVideo" autoplay muted loop>
        <source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4" type="video/mp4">
 </video>
<div>
      <a id="bVideo" href="#">Pause video</a>       
</div>
```

I want it to be paused or to be played any time. And text change on button respectively. I am not sure, whether the code correct is (as I am newbie), but I am pretty sure it has to work :)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var vid = document.getElementById("#myVideo");
    var vidB = $("#bVideo");
    var textContent = vidB.text();

    $(vidB).click(function(){
        switch (textContent){
            case "pause video":
                $(vid).get(0).pause();
                // $(vid).trigger('pause');
                $(vidB).text("play video");
                break;
            case "play video":
                $(vid).get(0).play();
                // $(vid).trigger('play');
                $(vidB).text("pause video");
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    });
 });
```

I have tried different constructions, non of them worked.

Here is jsfiddle link [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/tjr58s5L/2/)

Any help and critique will be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't change the value of the variable `textContent` and the initial value doesn't match the case `Pause video` vs `pause video`.
vidB is already a jQuery object so no need to wrap it in `$()`
vid === $(vid).get(0)
Takes an id as the parameter not a selector(notice no #)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");
    var vidB = $("#bVideo");

    vidB.click(function(){
        switch (vidB.text()){
            case "Pause video":
                vid.pause();
                vidB.text("play video");
                break;
            case "play video":
                vid.play();
                vidB.text("Pause video");
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<video id="myVideo" autoplay muted loop>
        <source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4" type="video/mp4">
 </video>
<div>
      <a id="bVideo" href="#">Pause video</a>       
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, but doesn't work also. `javascript.js:19 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'pause' of null`  I've tried also jsfiddle. There is also an error in console  after I click "pause video" `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #` but it is in jQuery library - jquery.min.js

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you for your help! It worked perfectly! :)